# Make list item fadeout animation to display detail of the list (Ionic)

Tags: angularjs, animation, ionic-framework, listitem

How to make listview simialr to below image. i.e When I click on the list item info button it should show fadeout animation to display detail of the list.

[Please refer image for the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cn3Gu.png)

Answer (score 1):

Angular comes with jQuery light.  Just add an event listener and use the animate.css library to toggle the class you want applied.

$('.your-element-class').toggleClass('your-animation-class');

https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/  -- Check out the fadeOut transition

Comment: Thanks for the solution.